# Google Fit not tracking/importing activities accurately

Tags: gps-tracking, fitness, google-fit, wearable

I've recently noticed that the Google Fit app has been *extremely* off when recording OR importing activity, but especially importing. I tracked several walks recently where my watch (Fossil Q Explorist) would report almost exactly with another app on my phone (Strava) in terms of distance, time, and steps (see screenshots).

However, when this activity is imported into Google Fit (in this case, presumably from the watch, but it's occurred just with Strava imports as well), the distance and step counts are *much* lower, roughly 60% or less in some cases. Does anyone know what the cause is or how to fix this?

I wouldn't be so miffed, but

1. This is a widely used application run by a company with plenty of resources
2. I can't find bunches of other people with this problem
3. Google Fit is my only tracking option to earn $$ from my health insurance, so taking 15k steps to earn 10k is pretty annoying
4. Google Fit has even retconned itself and changed activities again afterward (screenshot included)
5. I feel like I've tried everything, including:

   - uninstall/reinstall the app
   - sign out/back in
   - wipe data
   - enable all permissions for Google Fit
   - track with other apps to ensure accuracy
   - import from another Google Fit device (watch)

Pixel 6 Pro, Android 13, Fossil Q Explorist (most recent update)

| [image: Strava] | [image: Google Fit 1] | [image: Google Fit 2] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Strava** | **Google Fit (almost immediately after finishing activity)** | **Google Fit, viewing the same activity the next day** |

| [image: Fossil Q Explorist 1] | [image: Fossil Q Explorist 2] | [image: Fossil Q Explorist 3] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Fossil Q Explorist 1** | **Fossil Q Explorist 2** | **Fossil Q Explorist 3** |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a solution, but it relates specifically to this situation in the fact that it *requires you to be using a smartwatch or other tracking device or that you track all activity through another app* to track your fitness data.

The idea here is you **don't** want Google Fit to do any automatic tracking, as it seems that's where the inconsistencies are introduced. To do this, you open the Google Fit app, open the "Profile" tab (with the icon of a person at the bottom right), tap the "Settings" gear, then disable "Track your activities."

After this, you can use other apps (Strava, Fitbit) that feed data into Google Fit and Fit will assume their data is correct since it can't overlay its own incorrect data on top.

More useful: you can still use the Google Fit app on a wearable (smartwatch, Wear OS), as this activity will show correctly within the Fit app on your phone now and match what you tracked it to be on your wearable.

In my specific situation, I ended up moving completely to the [Samsung Health](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.wear.shealth) tracking app on a Galaxy Wear 4 Classic, then using [Health Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.appyhapps.healthsync) (3rd party) to sync the activity to Google Fit. I tried using Google's [Health Connect Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.healthdata), but Samsung Health doesn't sync steps yet with this service.