# Google Fit doesn't record steps accurately

Tags: smartwatch, google-fit

I have been very frustrated trying to get an accurate record of steps in the Google Fit app. I have only one device, a Fitbit Sense watch, which counts my steps, and I have disactivated activity tracking in the Google Fit app. I have specified that Fit can receive steps data from another app. However, Google Fit always has a considerably lower number of steps. The difference is not consistent; it can be 70% to 80% of what the watch records. It is always lower.

The watch transmits the steps accurately to another app, so the fault cannot lie with the Fitbit Sense app.

I noticed that in the Fit app, the steps are broken down by minutes the walking started. Is Fit consistently rounding down?

I want the steps transmitted to Google Fit to be recorded as received, not reworked in any way. I have three apps which show steps; two are in agreement and one is way off. This is not satisfactory.

Comment: See my question/solution to this issue at the link; in summary I had to use a third-party sync tool to correct this issue. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/250826/google-fit-not-tracking-importing-activities-accurately

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Fitbit is the problem.  We have used Samsung Watch and Phone for years and the health app integrates the two readings.

- The watch is mainly recording arm swings
- The phone is mainly recording hip motion

The readings will be different.  If you walk without moving your upper body much then the watch may record a lower count.  Similarly, if the phone is in your pocket or handbag and is not moving much, it may have a lower reading.  It depends on how you are moving.